# Export data from FOUNDRY to external source

Tags: palantir-foundry

my aim is to export a dataset saved as a CSV in FOUNDRY to an external sftp server.

I have created a source following the documentation but I keep on getting the error:

```
Could not load file listing

The agent failed to execute this explorer command: com.palantir.magritte.plugin.sftp.SftpClientException:Borrowing connection for ls failed: 
{exception message=UnknownHostKey: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX. RSA key fingerprint is XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, path=/}
```

My YAML looks like:

```
type: magritte-sftp
hostname: XXXX.XXXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
port: 22
username: XXXXXX
password: '{{PASSWORD}}'
rootDirectory: /
```

Comment: is the host whitelisted and have you set the correct https certificates?

Answer (score 0):

Try `dig <YOUR_URL>` in a terminal. This should expose IP addresses behind your DNS. Allowlist them. Job done.